# TestWnd::OnPaint() is not invoked

Tags: mfc

I am new to MFC and in below code `OnPaint()` is not invoked.

```
 //TestWnd.H
    #ifndef TESTWND
    #define TESTWND
    #include<afxwin.h>
    //window 
    class TestWnd:public CFrameWnd
        {
        public:
            TestWnd();

        protected:

        afx_msg  void onPaint();
        DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

        };  

    #endif


    //TestWnd.cpp

    #include"TestWnd.h"

    TestWnd::TestWnd()
        {
        Create (NULL, _T ("The Hello Application"),
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
            CRect(120, 100, 700, 480), NULL);
        }

    void TestWnd ::onPaint()
        {
        MessageBox(_T("The window has been PAINTED!!!"));

        //CPaintDC dc(this);

        //CRect crec;
        //GetClientRect(&crec);

        //dc.DrawText(_T("Hello"),-1, &crec, DT_SINGLELINE/* | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER*/);
        }


    BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(TestWnd,CFrameWnd)

        ON_WM_PAINT()
    END_MESSAGE_MAP()

    //TestApp.h
    #ifndef TESTAPP
    #define TESTAPP

    #include<afxwin.h>

    class TestApp:public CWinApp
        {
        public:
            virtual BOOL InitInstance();
        };

    #endif


    //TestApp.cpp
    #include "TestApp.h"
    #include "TestWnd.h"

    TestApp g_obj;

    BOOL TestApp::InitInstance()
        {
        m_pMainWnd = new TestWnd;
        m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(m_nCmdShow);
        //m_pMainWnd->UpdateWindow();

        return TRUE;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is very simple.

`ON_WM_PAINT` requires a handler named `OnPaint`. You implemented a handler named `onPaint`. Because there is a default implementation the default `CFrameWnd::OnPaint` is called.

Rename your handler to `OnPaint`.

Comment: Andrew it worked.Thanks for solution and removing extra code.